# Editing ArcGIS metadata elements using Python?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, xml, metadata

I have a shapefile with an xml metadata file. Most of the elements are pre-populated using the previous editions xml file. However, I am trying to automatically update the current edition within a larger script.

I cannot update my Python library with any new modules (for example the metadata module seen in other questions) as I am using a work computer which is locked down and cannot install anything.

The three elements that need updating are the title, the revision date and the edition date.

I have managed to update these using the tree and an index to find the tags.

However, how do I search for the metadata element using the tag title? So for example, the the edition date tag is "redEdDate".

In addition, will the metadata tree index ever change if/when additional information is added? Or do the trees have a set format, therefore the same indexes. Im worried that any update to ArcGIS metadata, will affect the tree, and therefore the index for the specific tags mentioned above, and cause error within the script.

The issue above is shown via the script below. Both datasets use the ArcGIS metadata format. However the same tags have different indexes. For example, the MCMS Polygon dataset uses an index of "root[4][0][0]" for the edition date. However the MCMS Exclusion Zone edition date has an index of "root [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGGtc.png)[0][0]".

[image]

[image]

[image: metadata tree]

My script so far is:

```
import arcpy, os, sys, datetime
import xml
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
ws = arcpy.env.workspace = r"path/to/folder"
today = datetime.date.today()
date = today.strftime("%Y%m%d")

#Update the MCMS polygon metadata titles, update date and edition date
for f in os.listdir(ws):
#Find the polygon xml file    
    if f.endswith("A.shp.xml"):
        fpath = os.path.join(ws, f)
#Identify the metadata tree      
        tree = ET.parse(fpath)
        root = tree.getroot()
#Set the title and date variables to the relevant metadata tag index
        editiondate = root[4][0][0]
        reviseddate = root[4][0][5][0]
        title = root[4][0][7]
#Update the tags with the new data
        editiondate.text = today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        reviseddate.text = today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + "T00:00:00"
        title.text = "MCMS (polygon)"
#Write the updates to the xml file
        tree.write(fpath)


#Update the MCMS exclusion metadata titles, update date and edition date
for f in os.listdir(ws):
#Find the exclusion zone xml file       
    if f.endswith("Zones.shp.xml"):
        fpath = os.path.join(ws, f)
#Identify the metadata tree  
        tree = ET.parse(fpath)
        root = tree.getroot()
#Set the title and date variables to the relevant metadata tag index
        editiondate = root[3][0][0]
        reviseddate = root[3][0][5][0]
        title = root[3][0][7]
#Update the tags with the new data
        editiondate.text = today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
        reviseddate.text = today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + "T00:00:00"
        title.text = "MCMS Exclusion Zones"
#Write the updates to the xml file
        tree.write(fpath)
```

Comment: Can you post what the XML File looks like?  It is hard to troubleshoot without knowing the structure of the tree.

Comment: The structure of the tree is the ArcGIS format xml. Are these always consistent across different geometry? At the moment I'm using indexes to locate tags, but how do I search for them instead? The structure may change over time which will cause an issue with the index in the future.

Comment: I have added additional information and a screenshot of the metadata tree

Comment: Thanks for posting your xml code.  I have added an answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have some comments/suggestions for you.  You mention that you do not have any admin privileges on your machine to be able to install the metadata module.  Good news here, you don't need admin to install python packages/modules.  You do if you're using a binary install, however, most modules can be installed using [pip](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip).  You can just download pip and put it in your `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.x\Scripts` folder.

You can also just download python packages and just place the modules somewhere in your `PYTHONPATH` such as `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.x\Lib\site-packages`.  The flaws with this is you could be missing some dependencies, but that is where pip will be the better option as it *should* install all dependencies as well.

However, with all that being said, I have never used the metadata module, but I believe the builtin [xml](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) module will do everything you need.  I actually built a wrapper a while back that has convenience methods for working with `xml` files (see below). You can try this to see if it helps.

As for hardcoding indices in your script for the metadata, I would avoid doing this.  I am not certain if ArcGIS will add future elements to the metadata, but if anything does get added/deleted, it could definitely mess up the indices in your current structure.  It is best to get at the elements by name.  You can use the `xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.find()` or `xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findall()` methods to accomplish this.

Here is the wrapper I built for working with `xml` files:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree, Element, SubElement, Comment, tostring, parse, fromstring, fromstringlist
from xml.dom import minidom
from xml.sax.saxutils import escape, unescape
import os
import codecs

HTML = {
    '"': "&quot;",
    "'": "&apos;",
    ">": "&gt;",
    "<": "&lt;",
    }

HTML_UNESC = {v:k for k,v in HTML.iteritems()}

class BaseXML(object):
    def __init__(self, xml_file):
        """base class for xml files"""
        self.document = xml_file
        if isinstance(xml_file, list):
            # we have a list of strings?
            self.tree = fromstringlist(xml_file)

        elif isinstance(xml_file, basestring) and not os.path.isfile(xml_file) and '<' in xml_file:
            # we have a string?
            self.tree = fromstring(xml_file)

        elif os.path.exists(xml_file):
            self.tree = parse(self.document)

        else:
            raise IOError('Invalid Input for XML file')

        self.directory = os.path.dirname(self.document)
        self.root = self.tree.getroot()
        self.parent_map = {}

        # make static copy
        self._backup = parse(self.document).getroot()

        # initialize parent map
        self.updateParentMap()

    @staticmethod
    def iterElm(root, tag_name=None, childrenOnly=True, **kwargs):
        """return generator for tree

        Optional:
            tag_name -- name of tag
            kwargs -- optional key word args to filter by tag attributes

        """
        for tag in root.iter(tag_name):
            if all([tag.get(k) == v for k,v in kwargs.iteritems()]):
                if childrenOnly and tag != root:
                    yield tag

                elif not childrenOnly:
                    yield tag

    def elmHasTags(self, root, tag, **kwargs):
        """tests if there are valid tags

        tag_name -- name of tag to check for
        """
        gen = self.iterElm(root, tag, **kwargs)
        try:
            gen.next()
            return True

        except StopIteration:
            return False

    def findChild(self, parent, child_name, **kwargs):
        """find child anywhwere under parent element

        child_name -- name of tag
        kwargs -- keyword args to filter
        """
        for c in self.iterElm(parent, child_name, **kwargs):
            return c

    def findChildren(self, parent, child_name, **kwargs):
        """find all children anywhwere under parent element,
        returns a list of elements.

        child_name -- name of tag
        kwargs -- keyword args to filter
        """
        return [c for c in self.iterElm(parent, child_name, **kwargs)]

    def validateElm(self, elm, elm_name=None, **kwargs):
        """validates whether input is an Element name or Element object.  If it
        is an Element name, it will return the Element object with that name and
        any additional key word args

        Required:
            elm -- element name or Element object
            elm_name -- name of Element.tag, only used if elm is a string.

        Optional:
            kwargs -- keyword argument filters, required if elm is a string
        """
        if isinstance(elm, Element):
            return elm
        elif isinstance(elm, basestring):
            return self.getElm(elm_name, **kwargs)

    def updateParentMap(self):
        """updates the parent_map dictionary"""
        self.parent_map = {c:p for p in self.tree.iter() for c in p}

    def countParents(self, elm, parent_name, **kwargs):
        """Count the number of parents an element has of a certain name, does
        heiarchal search

        Required:
            elm -- child element for which to search parents
            parent_name -- name of parent tag

        Optional:
            kwargs -- keyword argument filters
        """
        count = 0
        parent = self.getParent(elm, parent_name, **kwargs)
        while parent != None:
            count += 1
            parent = self.getParent(parent, parent_name, **kwargs)
        return count

    def getParent(self, child, parent_name=None, **kwargs):
        """get parent element by tag name or first parent

        Required:
            child -- child element for which to find parent
            tag_name -- name of tag

        Optional:
            kwargs -- optional key word args to filter by tag attributes

        """
        parent = self.parent_map.get(child)
        if parent is None:
            return None
        if parent_name is None:
            return parent
        else:
            if parent.tag == parent_name and all([parent.get(k) == v for k,v in kwargs.iteritems()]):
                return parent
            else:
                return self.getParent(parent, parent_name, **kwargs)

    def elmHasParentOfName(self, child, parent_name=None, **kwargs):
        """checks if a child element has a parent of an input name

        Required:
            child -- child element for which to find parent
            tag_name -- name of tag

        Optional:
            kwargs -- optional key word args to filter by tag attributes
        """
        return self.getParent(child, parent_name, **kwargs) is not None

    def getElm(self, tag_name, root=None, **kwargs):
        """get specific tag by name and kwargs filter

        Required:
            tag_name -- name of tag

        Optional:
            root -- root element to start with, defaults to the ElementTree
            kwargs -- optional key word args to filter by tag attributes
        """
        for tag in self.iterTags(tag_name, root=root, **kwargs):
            return tag

    def findChildrenWithKeys(self, elm, tag_name=None, keys=[]):
        """finds children of a parent Element of a specific tag and/or if that element has
        attributes matching the names found in input keys list

        Required:
            elm -- root element

        Optional: (should implement one or both of these)
            tag_name -- name of tags to search for
            keys -- list of attribute keys to check for
        """
        if isinstance(keys, basestring):
            keys = [keys]

        return [c for c in self.iterChildren(elm, tag_name) if c is not None and all(map(lambda k: k in c.keys(), keys))]

    @staticmethod
    def prettify(elem):
        """Return a pretty-printed XML string for the Element."""
        rough_string = tostring(elem, 'utf-8')
        reparsed = minidom.parseString(rough_string)
        pretty =  reparsed.toprettyxml(indent="  ").split('\n')
        return '\n'.join([l for l in pretty if l.strip()])

    def iterTags(self, tag_name=None, root=None, **kwargs):
        """return generator for tree

        Optional:
            tag_name -- name of tag
            root -- optional root tag to start from, if None specified defaults
                to the ElementTree
            kwargs -- optional key word args to filter by tag attributes
        """
        if isinstance(root, Element):
            return self.iterElm(root, tag_name, **kwargs)
        else:
            return self.iterElm(self.tree, tag_name, **kwargs)

    @staticmethod
    def iterChildren(parent, tag=None, childrenOnly=True, **kwargs):
        """iterate all children of an element based on **kwargs filter

        Required:
            parent -- element for which to search children

        Optional:
            tag -- name of tag for filter
            childrenOnly -- return children only, if false, iterator will start
                at parent
            kwargs -- optional key word args to filter by tag attributes
        """
        for elm in parent.iter(tag):
            if all([elm.get(k) == v for k,v in kwargs.iteritems()]):
                if childrenOnly and elm != parent:
                    yield elm

                elif not childrenOnly:
                    yield elm

    def hasTags(self, tag_name, root=None, **kwargs):
        """tests if there are valid tags

        tag_name -- name of tag to check for
        """
        gen = self.iterTags(tag_name, **kwargs)
        try:
            gen.next()
            return True

        except StopIteration:
            return False

    def addElm(self, tag_name, attrib={}, root=None, update_map=True):
        """add SubElement to site or existing element

        Required:
            tag_name -- name of new element

        Optional:
            attrib -- dictionary of attributes for new element
            root -- parent element for which to add element.  If none specified,
                element will be added to <Site> root.
            update_map -- option to update parent map, you may want to disable this
                when making many changes during an iterative process. Default is True.
        """
        if root is None:
            root = self.root
        sub = SubElement(root, tag_name, attrib)
        if update_map:
            self.updateParentMap()
        return sub

    def restore(self):
        """reverts all changes back to the state at which the Site.xml document was
        when this class was initialized
        """
        self.__init__(self.document)

    def save(self):
        """saves the changes"""
        with codecs.open(self.document, 'w', 'utf-8') as f:
            f.write(self.prettify(self.root))

    def __iter__(self):
        """create generator"""
        for elm in iter(self.tree.iter()):
            yield elm
```

To use this, save it in your `C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.x\Lib\site-packages` (or better yet a network share where it can be imported from) as something like `xmlhelper.py`.  To do some of the above stuff, you can do something like the following:

```
import xmlhelper # make sure this is importable, if not use sys.path.append(r'path_to_module_parent_folder') first
import os
import datetime
import glob

ws = arcpy.env.workspace = r"path/to/folder"
today = datetime.date.today()
date = today.strftime("%Y%m%d")

# find all metadata files in path
for f in glob.glob(os.path.join(ws, '*.shp.xml')):

    # user wrapper here
    doc = xmlhelper.BaseXML(f)

    # get edition date and set it
    editiondate = doc.getElm('resEdDate')
    editiondate.text = today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

    # update revise date
    revisedate = doc.getElm('reviseDate')
    revisedate.text = today.strftime("%Y-%m-%d") + "T00:00:00"

    # update title
    title = doc.getElm('resTitle')  # should be the same, regardless of shapefile?

    # may want to be a little more explicit with if statement here....
    if f.endswith('A.shp.xml'):
        title.text = 'MCMS (polygon)'
    elif f.endswith('Zones.shp.xml'):
        title.text = 'MCMS Exclusion Zones'

    # save it
    doc.save()

print 'done'
```

To test to make sure it is working, I would make a copy of the data on your desktop first to try this out on that.  If it works, then you can run it against your production data.  **The code above is untested.**

Comment: Ive tried to implement your xmlwrapper, but when I try to use doc.save(), i get the following error: Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\xmlhelper.py", line 277, in save
    with codecs.open(self.document, 'w', 'utf-8') as f:
NameError: global name 'codecs' is not defined.

Comment: Ohh, oops.  When I copied the code I missed the first line, which is `import codecs`.  Once you import that module, it should work.  I just edited this to include importing `codecs`.

Comment: Thanks for that. It worked a charm. I actually tried to import that module into my script. I didnt clock on that i needed to import it into the xmlhelper module. Cheers

Comment: Glad it worked for you, I use this wrapper for all things XML.  I did edit the question though to remove the `arcpy` tags as this has more to deal with general Python programming against an ArcGIS metadata XML file.

Comment: Hi mate, im trying to use this wrapper again. However having trouble finding a specific element. For example, the element "linkage" is used multiple times. Trying to locate a specific element called linkage, but the "getelm" only finds the first one.

Comment: That's where you would want to use the `.iterTags('linkage')` method.  This will iterate over all of the linkage tags.  You can also take advantage of the `kwargs` argument (keyword arguments) to further narrow down the search on one or more elements.  For example, if you had two linkage elements who had a `type` property with different values,  you could find the find the first like this: `doc.getElm('linkage', type='Type A')` and the second the same way: `doc.getElm('linkage', type='Type B')`.  Most of the selectors use that same kwargs option, so you could use it with `iterTags()` too.

Comment: arcpy_metadata only requires arcpy so adding it to the python path as you describe works.